# psycopg2 UniqueViolation error while inserting in empty table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Assuming I have user table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id SERIAL UNIQUE,
    email character varying(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username character varying(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

And trigger on it defined in this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_username() RETURNS                       
TRIGGER AS $insert_username$                                               
    BEGIN                                                                  
        NEW.username := SPLIT_PART(NEW.email, '@', 1);                     
        RETURN NEW;                                                        
    END;                                                                   
$insert_username$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;                                        
CREATE TRIGGER insert_username BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE                     
ON user FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE                           
PROCEDURE insert_username();
```

Then using psycopg2 I am trying to populate this table with data from another database. Here's the piece of code from migrations module I made and the query string responsible for this:

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
from data_migration.database import cursor

query = 'INSERT INTO user("id", "email") VALUES %s'
values = [[1, 'example1@email.com'], [2, 'example2@email.com']]

execute_values(cursor, query, values)
```

It had worked as expected until I implemented this trigger. Now it still works well when I'm inserting single row from postgres shell or using psycopg2 but it fails on execute_values and gives me UniqueViolation error even if the table is completely empty:

```
UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(kjhmgfd) already exists.
```

There's a lot more fields and code around it and of course, I can get rid of this trigger and do the same on python side. But I'd really like to keep it. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but I've spent some hours on it and still have no idea why it happens. Would be very helpful if someone could help me find it out. Thanks!

Comment: From the error, it looks like there may be multiple users with kjhmgfd@* . Can you check the source data?

Comment: @Jeremy yes, that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seemed that was my lack of attention to the source data. There I have some users with the same local-part but the different domain in emails. Thanks to Jeremy for pointing it out. Ended up with modifying the trigger in this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_username() RETURNS                            
TRIGGER AS $insert_username$                                                    
    DECLARE                                                                     
        counter INTEGER := 0;                                                   
        new_username VARCHAR(256);                                              
        attempt_username VARCHAR(256);                                          
        is_exists BOOLEAN;                                                      
    BEGIN                                                                       
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_username_exists(un VARCHAR(256))          
            RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$                                               
            DECLARE                                                             
                is_row_exists BOOLEAN;                                          
            BEGIN                                                               
                SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=un) INTO is_row_exists;                          
                RETURN is_row_exists;                                           
            END;                                                                
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;                                                    

        new_username := SPLIT_PART(NEW.email, '@', 1);                          
        attempt_username := new_username;                                       

        LOOP                                                                    
            SELECT is_username_exists(attempt_username) INTO is_exists;         
            EXIT WHEN is_exists IS FALSE;                                       
            counter := counter + 1;                                             
            attempt_username := new_username || counter;                        
        END LOOP;                                                               

        NEW.username := attempt_username;                                       

        RETURN NEW;
    END;                                                                        
$insert_username$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;                                             
CREATE TRIGGER insert_username BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE                          
ON user FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_username();
```